# GPick preview isn't same as present windows on desktop (It keeps showing my first captured screen!)

Tags: color, software-recommendation

I explained my problem with GPick software twice [here](https://github.com/thezbyg/gpick/issues/150) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122095/gpick-always-show-first-captured-screen-not-the-currently-one).
The problem that I opened this question here is GPick doesn't show my current screen and opened window! It just keeps showing the first captured screen (my background) and won't update either! I also tried to change GPick preferences but no luck! Please let me know if you now how can I solve it!

*Hope to opened this issue in a correct forum! Thanks.*

Comment: Sorry, but this is off-topic here since it's really a support question about software. Few here will install software they might not even use, just to try find out what's wrong. Perhaps another stackexchange site like SuperUser might be a better fit?

Comment: You apparently already raised the issue with the developer on GitHub (though apparently with fewer details than here), which is exactly the right place to do this. This was an hour ago; give them some time to react.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry guys! Thanks for your replies anyway.